# He said yes..she said no..they went back and forth..they agreed to

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

To call it a Prime.

S, N, O are 3 distinct digits that are to be determined by you so that their conclusion is right

Full concatenated number: SNOSNOS

Comment: I'm afraid it's unclear what you are asking..

Comment: Figuring out the prime number which corresponds to snosnos

Comment: If the answer provided thus far is *the answer* then this would be far too broad a question and far too mechanical a solution path to be an on-topic puzzle here.  I hope there's more to it than meets the eye; but if there is, it's too subtle for me. You might want to make *the puzzle* a bit more explicit, so folks have an inkling of what they're trying to solve.

Comment: @Rubio Knowing this OP, I don't think a mechanical solution path (computer program) would be expected. But there might be a criterion missing in the question, as usually there's only one single solution to their puzzles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran it through a program and it spat these out as the possibilities:

> ```
> 1231231
> 1261261
> 1281281
> 1381381
> 1491491
> 1581581
> 1621621
> 1641641
> 1671671
> 1731731
> 1741741
> 1791791
> 1821821
> 1831831
> 1851851
> 1861861
> 1921921
> 1941941
> 1951951
> 3253253
> 3283283
> 3563563
> 3763763
> 3853853
> 3863863
> 3973973
> 3983983
> 9139139
> 9149149
> 9239239
> 9269269
> 9319319
> 9379379
> 9419419
> 9439439
> 9679679
> 9689689
> 9829829
> 9839839
> 9859859
> 9869869
> ```

I checked some at random against a list so I think they're correct.

Comment: I'm intrigued that there are no solutions starting/ending in 7. Is there a simple explanation?

Comment: Oh of course, the remaining part is a multiple of 1001 which is a multiple of 7.